# HTML: Child input with width 100% is larger than fixed width parent table

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a rather strange situation..

I'm trying to make a text input fill its entire table cell, but when using `width:100%` on it you can see that it becomes larger than it's parent, even though no padding or margin is used.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecxdkwwz/

I can see some change when applying `margin:0px` to the input as it actually go smaller, but it's still larger than the above div and I really wonder why.. (I'm using firefox)

Comment: I used <input type="text" style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;"></input> and it was smaller than the parent.

Comment: That's because inputs automatically add some padding and margin. In firefox, it has a margin of 2 and a padding of 1 all around.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why the dimensions weren't the same. Is this behavior the same on all browsers?

Comment: Hum, actually even when removing all padding and margin you can see that it's still slightly bigger than the above div.. why? http://jsfiddle.net/benit2/4T3qu/2/

I think it's the border doing this but is there a way to make the border wrap around the input and keeping the same width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the following css and it solved the problem

css

```
input[type = 'text']{
 width:100%;
 background:lightblue;
 box-shadow:none;
 text-shadow:none;
 border:none;
```

}

WORKING CODE:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/ZJ45d/4/)

Comment: Actually if you want to keep the border, you need to override the default margin and padding to 0, as mentioned in the above comments.